# Jenkins: Cucumber Test Runners execution order

Tags: java, jenkins, cucumber

In my automation project I have two test runners:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = ".",
        plugin = {"json:target/json","rerun:rerun.txt","io.qameta.allure.cucumberjvm.AllureCucumberJvm"})
public class MainTest {
}





@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "@rerun.txt",
        plugin = {"json:target/json","rerun:rerun.txt","io.qameta.allure.cucumberjvm.AllureCucumberJvm"})
public class FailedScenarioRerunTest {
}
```

I want to run first MainTest and next FailedScenarioTest, how to do it?
In theory test should run with features alphabetical order, at local machine it's exactly like that, but in Jenkins order is not alphabetical.
anyone had to deal with such a problem?

Comment: What is the reason you want to run them in a particular order?

Comment: I run all test, and after that i want to execute failed scenarios

Comment: Ok, so your question is how to run the failed tests after the first run? Or do you need them to run in alphabetical order each run?

Comment: i have over 20 test runners, how to run them in specified order

Answer (score 0):

Answer is:

```
<runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
```

in surefire configuration in pom.xml